# "18 months away from my 20"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In the movie *Michael Clayton*, a conversation takes place between Michael Clayton, lawyer, and his cop friend.

> Cop: Now I owe this scumbag and his wife who's a complete piece of shit in my unit. Now I owe them both my balls.
>
> Michael: I'm sorry. You know I am.
>
> Cop (imitating Michael): "Nobody will know it's me." You know what happens they don't bury this, that I gave you this?
>
> Michael: It's bad. I know it.
>
> Cop: I'm **18 months away from my 20**. You just put my pension in jeopardy.

It appears **20** here means retirement. I know **20** is a slang word meaning location, but what does it mean here?

Comment: I agree with Mike, the cop is saying he is 18 months away from retiring after 20 years service.

Comment: Interesting to see **20** there as a sort of wordplay.  Where's his mind? Its 20 is on his 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case "20" means "20 years of service," meaning he is likely eligible for pension and/or other retirement benefits at that point.

Comment: To be clear: he could “retire” after 10, 15, or 19.5 years - or 25 or 30 years. It’s just that after 20 years of service in many professions, you qualify for significant retirement benefits. It’s used to keep people in those professions for longer.

Comment: @JohnBurger I've clarified my answer.